# Can't Make Square and Triangle Waves

Tags: wave, waveform

I have the following c++ code for making a sine wave using SFML, which i got from https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Play-Sine-Wave.

```cpp
for (unsigned i = 0; i < SAMPLES ; i++) {
  raw[i] = AMPLITUDE * sin(x * TWO_PI);
  x += increment;
}
```

I tried to make a square and triangle wave based off this code -

```cpp
//Square
    else if (wave == 1) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++) {
            raw[i] = AMPLITUDE * (sin(x * TWO_PI) < 0 ? -1 : 1);
            x += increment;
        }
    }
    //Triangle
    else if (wave == 2) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < SAMPLES ; i++) {
            raw[i] = ((AMPLITUDE * sin(x * TWO_PI)) >= 0) ? =AMPLITUDE : -AMPLITUDE;
            x += increment;
        }
    }
```

They both produce some sort of weird wave when I look at it on an osciloscope.

**edit-** My PC's audio jack hooked up to my scope.

The issue isn't with the code as when I look at a square wave from youtube, a similar wave appears. This is the Image -
[image]

Comment: I'd start by setting the output frequency very low (like 1hz). If the wave looks correct, then you know it's something frequency dependent, and probably an issue with the dac circuit. If it's still wrong, it's probably a software bug.

Comment: Who knows how you managed to do this.  It was a challenge to duplicate https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVzll.png  Here I advanced  the triangle 45 degrees and showed shared current 8)

Comment: @Drew if i set the output to 1hz, it just twitches.

Comment: make it DC coupled on scope

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 it is dc doupling

Comment: Do you understand how the signal I created works and I started with triangle square waves distorted by two RC filters. This is how your code is working.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 It's not just the code, when I search for a youtube video of a triangle wave or square wave, it outputs a similar figure

Comment: Write the result of the c++ code to a file and then plot it on the screen with a plotting program. If it looks correct, then the circuit connecting the code to the scope has the problem.

Comment: @AJN I did, and it looked fine

Comment: I guess your hardware is bad, whatever that is and same with those video’s

Comment: I would suggest that you add a schematic of the circuit as well as a clear, high resolution, cropped, photograph of the circuit.

Comment: You can't fix this in C : you need to increase (or remove : but that'll leave a DC offset) the coupling capacitor after the DAC.

Comment: @AJN I have no circut it's just my pc's audio jack hooked up to my scope lmao

Comment: @user_1818839 increase or remove what?

Comment: @user_1818839 The scope waveform time scale appears to be `500 us`. It should be a high enough frequency to be able to neglect any capacitors in the path; right ?

Comment: Is `sf::Int16` a signed or unsigned datatype ?

Comment: If it's your PC's audio jack, ... tough luck, that's what you get.